# GitHub shared repository

Tags: github

I want to share on my personal GitHub repositories page a repository uploaded by my collaborator on his personal GitHub page. I have collaborator permission in the repo's admin settings and I can see the repository in my GitHub after clicking on my image and clicking on repositories. Moreover, the repository is public.

However, the repo is not visible on my GitHub repositories page.
**How can I link the repository on my personal GitHub repository page?**

I was thinking to fork the repository, but in such a way if some of us modify the original repository the changes are not visible in the one I forked. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If forking allows you to list that repository in your GitHub repository pages, then all you need to do is:

- make any change in the original repository (since your have collaborator rights)
- do not commit directly in your fork
- fetch from the original repo URL (named "upstream"), merge `upstream/main` and push from a local clone of your fork, to update that forked repository.

That is:

```sh
git clone /url/fork
cd fork
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo

# after modifications to the original repo content (new commits on main)
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/main
git push
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer (+1). Do I have to make the last step (to show the modifications of the original repo in my repo's page) every time someone modifies the original repo? Is there a way to avoid to do it manually each time and still make the two repository identical or even better show in my repo's page the original repository (kind of showing a link to the original repo)?

Comment: @Gio Yes, through script: https://github.com/ElfSundae/sync-git-mirror